# How to get the first and third word using map function in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to retrieve the first and third index valueb of each line as an arrray using the `map` function.

The following will produce an array of the first word:

```
File.map(l => l.split(" ")(0)).collect()
```

I've tried the following but without any luck:

```
File.map(l => l.split(" ")(0)(2)).collect()

File.map(l => l.split(" ")(0,2)).collect()

File.map(l => l.split(" ")(0)+(2)).collect()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you could do, You need to return the tuple from the map function as below.

```
File.map(l => (l.split(" ")(0), l.split(" ")(2)))
    .collect()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as a pattern match:

```
File.
  map {
    _.split(" ").take(3) match {
      case Array(firstWord, _, thirdWord) => (firstWord, thirdWord)
      // Consider handling cases where there are fewer than three words
    }
  }.
  collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting `RDD[Array[String]]` then you can do the following

```
File.map(line => line.split(" ")).map(words => Array(words(0), words(2))).collect()
```